# QT QLineEdit focusout

Tags: qt

I have a QLineedit with mask and qvalidator (subclassed)

How can i prevent to move away the focus if the input isn't match the mask or validator ?

Because neither mask nor qvalidator don't prevent to move away focus from QLineEdit.

And editingfinished isn't work because :

void QLineEdit::editingFinished()

This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus. Note that if there is a validator() or inputMask() set on the line edit and enter/return is pressed, the editingFinished() signal will only be emitted if the input follows the inputMask() and the validator() returns QValidator::Acceptable."

```
void MainWindow:n_lineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    if (ui->lineEdit->text() != "1111") ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
}
```

So mask (an validator) doesn't work together with editingFinsihed signal.

plus i have tried this

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *filterObj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (filterObj == ui->lineEdit ) {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut) {
            if (ui->lineEdit->text() != "1111") { ui->lineEdit-`>setFocus();};
        return true;
        };
    };
return false;
}
```

thank you Attila

Answer (score 0):

From the Qt's doc:

> Note that if there is a validator set on the line edit, the
>   returnPressed()/editingFinished() signals **will only be emitted** if the
>   validator returns `QValidator::Acceptable`.

But you can set a focus on every event, not only for `FocusOut`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *filterObj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (filterObj == ui->lineEdit ) 
        ui->lineEdit->setFocus();

    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {
        QKeyEvent* e = (QKeyEvent*)event;

        if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Return
            || e->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
        {
            /* do what you want here */
        }
    }

    return QObject::eventFilter(filterObj, event); // usual process other events        
}
```